# Returning a method in a void

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
package zargclient;

public class Skin {
    protected String ID = "http://i.imgur.com/";
    protected String Name = "";
    protected boolean Locked = false;
    protected boolean StaffName = false;
    public static void main(String ID, String N, boolean L, boolean SN) {
        Skin Result = new Skin();
        Result.ID = ID;
        Result.Name = N;
        Result.Locked = L;
        Result.StaffName = SN;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I want to add `return Result;` to that code, but I can't since Java won't allow it. I can't use specific data arrays such as `int[] Items = {1, 2, 3};` since I need to have the array contain strings and booleans.

Is there a solution around this, and if so, can any of you please explain it? I'm new to Java, so it'd be greatly appreciated <3

If you're wondering why I am using this: It's for a project I'm working on, where all 'skins' derive from this Skin class.

Comment: Get the main method **out** of the Skin class as it serves you no benefit being there. Instead if you want a viable OOP compliant and useful Java class, then give your class a constructor and getters and setters methods. Read some intro chapters on Java classes as they will help you greatly moving forward. Note that your question and code suggests that you're guessing at coding without first reading and studying the subject. Don't do this.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't name `main`a method which is not a real main method. A real main method takes a String[] as argument. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you really want to return the result, then the method should return Skin, not void.

Comment: If I put the `main()` method outside the class, it asks me to put it in a class, so should I put it in a class, or keep it in this one?

Comment: Also, please conform to Java coding conventions: Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`). Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`), and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`).

Comment: All methods belong to classes (or enums or interfaces) so it should be inside a class. But if it's a regular method and not `main`, you just need to change its return type to `int` instead of `void` - but you need to write a real `main` that will call it`.

Comment: Thank you @RealSkeptic. I'll try that and edit my question soon! :)

Comment: I don't get the downvotes, remember when you started to learn java. This clearly doesn't fullfil any of the SO cirteria of a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the method signature of `main` is `void`, you should create a new method which returns an Object of type `Skin`.

```
package com.steve.research;

public class Skin {
    protected String ID = "http://i.imgur.com/";
    protected String Name = "";
    protected boolean Locked = false;
    protected boolean StaffName = false;

    public static Skin createSkin(String ID, String N, boolean L, boolean SN) {
        Skin result = new Skin();
        result.ID = ID;
        result.Name = N;
        result.Locked = L;
        result.StaffName = SN;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you could split the code into two classes, `Skin` and `SkinFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't give you a public rep since I don't have 15 rep myself yet. By far the most helpful person here!

Comment: No worries Sam, thanks for stopping by here and good luck further with learning java :)